# Call grandparent method in dojo with this.inherited

Tags: javascript, inheritance, dojo

I'm trying to make a customized subclass of a dojo widget (the *parent*, `dojox.mobile.ListItem`, which derives from the *grandparent*, `dijit._WidgetBase`) .

One of the methods that I want to override and modify from the parent contains a call to `this.inherited(arguments)`. This means that I can't just copy it directly into my subclass (because the `this.inherited` call from my method will call the parent class's method, not the grandparent's, as it did in the original context). I don't want to call the parent class's method as I'm deliberately adjusting what it does (I want to create different DOM elements to what `ListItem` creates). But I want to retain the standard grandparent class functionality, as `ListItem` does.

So I would like to call the grandparent class's method directly on the current object. Is there a way to do this? If not, how can I work around this problem?

Comment: I'm currently working around this with `dijit._WidgetBase.prototype.methodName()`, but don't know the benefits/pitfalls of this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dijit._WidgetBase.prototype.methodName()` will lose the scope of the child widget, which may or may not have consequences.  You should use

`dijit._WidgetBase.prototype.methodName.apply(this, arguments)`

Here is a fiddle to show what I mean

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/4nGCH/